# How to insert all elements from one immutable list into another at given index

Tags: javascript, pagination, redux, immutable.js

I need to insert the contents of an array (pure JS) into an immutable List at a given index.

I have a list like `[a,b,c,d,e]` which represents the ids at indexes `0 - 4` on the server. I then fetch an array `[j,k,l,m,n]` (which represents the id's at indices `9 - 14`). I want to merge the two lists so that I have:

`[a,b,c,d,e,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,j,k,l,m,n]`

It's possible to do `oldList.insert(9, nextList)` but this nests the whole `nextList` array into index `9` and not it's contents at indices `9 - 14`

I need something like the ES6/Next spread operator..

```
const ids = oldList.insert(10, ...next_ids)
```

But this isn't possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying your old list is like ['a', ''b', 'c', 'd'] and you want to insert the new list say ['e', 'f'] in between so the result would be like ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'd'].  Your constraint is that you can only use ES5 and no ES6 operators?

Comment: @seescode thanks for your response. I have edited my question to (hopefully) make it clearer what I'm after.

I now have a workaround which is to `setSize` on empty list, `concat` the next list and then `merge`. I'll leave it open in case there is a more succinct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution but be interested to know if there is a more succinct way..

```
const list = List( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] ) // Indices 0 - 5
const fetchResponse = ['j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'] // Indices 9 - 14
const nextList = List()
  .setSize(9) // The start index of fetched results
  .concat(List(fetchResponse))
  .mergeWith((next, last) => next || last, list) // Take new value at index if defined, otherwise old

console.log(nextList.toJS())
  -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', null, null, null, null, null, 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
```